# How to use two diffrent table for authentication in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am creating admin and api using cakePHP. Both admin and api side have login system.
There are two tables, one is `admins` that is for admin login. Another is `users` that is for api side login. 
So what I want is, if user come through admin side then it should chek from `admins` table and if users are coming from api it should check from `users` table. 
I have separated `admin` and `api` functionality in two different folder. 
So normal admin functionality I am working on `controller` folder. For `api` functionality I have created another folder inside `controller` folder, named as `Api`. 
So there are two `AppController.php` I am using. One is for `admin` and another is for api.

Here is how I am calling auth in `Controller\AppController.php` for admin

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth',[
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'admins',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ]
    ]);
```

This is how I am calling auth component for api login in `Controller\App\AppController.php`

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth',[
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'user',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ]
    ]);
```

Here is the login functionality for admin

```
public function login()
{
    $user = $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User');
    if($user){
         $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Venues'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        }
        else{
            $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login credential');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is login functionlity for api

```
public function login()
{
    $user = $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User');
    if($user){
         $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Venues'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
        }
        else{
            $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login credential');
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling `$this->Auth->identify();` from both login function. So maybe this is the issue. Is is possible to use different table for different auth.

Comment: Why different tables? Why not one with simple role logic?

Comment: If you namespace the appcontrollers to app/controller/api and app/controller/admin there shouldn‘t be any problems, or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, You can use `finder` method in Auth configurations (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)

Inside finder method You can use default model or load other models.